# html2canvas can not capture captcha images

Tags: jquery, html, screenshot, capture, html2canvas

Here is the html codes :

```
<div id="divPage">
div_Page
<br/>
<img id="captchaimglogin" src="https://www.emirates.com/account/english/login/login.aspx?cptLogin_captcha=86e2a65e-f170-43b6-9c87-41787ff64a35&t=88d296b19e5e8000&mode=ssl" border="0" />
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save PNG"/>
```

And here is jquery codes :

```
$(function() {
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#divPage"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
               }
         });
         html2canvas($("#btnSave"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
               }
         });
    });
});
```

And here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6FZkk/283/) link

How can i capture such these captcha images using with **html2canvas** or other ways?

Comment: *"So...why bother with capturing a `captcha`?"*, he says with suspicion. BTW, many implimentations of captcha's will have cross-domain content that will taint the canvas which will prevent capturing a captcha;

Comment: There is no suspicious activity, i just need to capture whole page including loaded captcha.

Comment: fair enough :-) I've posted an answer how to capture the page given that `captcha` will likely prevent html2canvas from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [HTML2Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html) documentation, you are able to use the `allowTaint` and `taintTest` configurations to allow cross-origin images.

```
onrendered: function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
           },
allowTaint: true,
taintTest: false
```

Comment: `allowTaint` is only half the solution. The server hosting the image(s) must also be configured to allow serving the image(s) to anonymous clients. ;-)

Comment: But does not work on captcha image directly. any idea? http://jsfiddle.net/6FZkk/287/

Comment: @MoonLight I have a feeling it is regarding markE's comment. The documentation also discussed the limitations of images.

Answer (score 1):

Detect and remove the `captcha` on the original page before running `html2canvas`.

Many implimentations of captcha's will have cross-domain content that will taint the canvas. Tainting a canvas will automatically prevent html2canvas from capturing the page...

Comment: Listen man, thanks for the answer. i accidently downvoted you and can't raise it again. so one of members vote this member up again and thanks for your attention.